# LocalStorage key disappears when I set a new one

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

This was working before just fine. But now when it sets another new one it always get removed, and viceversa. I'm only setting in two different functions, each of those have:

```
localStorage.setItem("d-token", res.token);
localStorage.setItem("t-token", res.token);
```

When I execute the function to set the d-token, t-token is removed, and when I set t-token, d-token is the one that gets removed which didn't happen before. I don't remember making any changes

I tried refreshing the page, but it still not working like it used to.

Comment: Changing one shouldn't affect the others. Can you show us the context of how you're setting them

Comment: It works in the console for me with example values just fine. Can you show some more context?

Comment: I have two functions async, connectT and connectD that make a GET request, the result of that I set the localstorage, for connectT t-token, and for connectD d-token. When I execute connectT it saves t-token but removes d-token, I do not know the reason why its happening. I have the LocalStorage.remove in other functions, but it gets removed when I try to add another. This didn't happen before.

Comment: Now trying things, I found out that in the useEffect, I put:  const dToken = localStorage.getItem("d-token");
    const tToken = localStorage.getItem("t-token"); And when I removed one, it stopped removing when adding. Why is this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.